# Hibernate - multi-language tables

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, database-design

I'm trying to build a multi-language database, so I've used [this database design](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8084/Creating-multilingual-websites-Part#databasegood) as a approach for mine.

Now I've two problems/questions:

1. I want to retrieve all `LocalizedEvent` for a given language and given categoryId. How can I make a inner join over the LocalizedCategory table with Hibernate Criteria API?

With SQL I would make this statement to get all `LocalizedEvent` + `LocalizedCategory`:

```
 SELECT * FROM event e
        INNER JOIN
    localized_event le ON (le.event_id = e.event_id)
        INNER JOIN
    localized_category lc ON (lc.category_id = e.category_id)
 WHERE
    le.locale = 'de' AND lc.locale = 'de'
```

My current approach looks like this without getting the `LocalizedCategory` (with Criteria API):

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(LocalizedEvent.class, "localizedEvent");
c.createAlias("localizedEvent.event", "event");
c.createAlias("event.category", "category");
c.add(Restrictions.eq("category.categoryId", categoryId));
c.add(Restrictions.eq("localizedEvent.locale", language));
```

2. I think my mapping is not 100% correct. The entity `LocalizedEvent` should have a property `localizedCategory`, but I don't want to save the ID of this `localizedCategory` (therefore I'm using the `@Transient` annotation) in the LocalizedEvent table, e.g. using a ManyToOne relation (joining `LOC_CATEGORY_ID`). But I think it's not possible to do this, isn't it? I would have to map this transient field to `LocalizedEvent` "manually", because Hibernate is not supporting this mapping (if I'm right). 
   (Using JDBC this property/mapping would cause no problems, because I can easily make my inner joins and assign the property `localizedCategory` to the `LocalizedEvent` in a RowMapper or so).

My entities looks like this:

**Event**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EVENT")
public class Event {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "EVENT_ID", unique = true)
    private Long eventId;

    @Column(name = "DATE")
    private Date date;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "event")
    private Set<LocalizedEvent> localizedEvents;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
    private Category category;
}
```

**LocalizedEvent**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOCALIZED_EVENT")
public class LocalizedEvent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "LOC_EVENT_ID")
    private Long locEventId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "EVENT_ID")
    private Event event;

    @Transient
    private LocalizedCategory localizedCategory;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "LOCALE")
    private String locale;
}
```

**Category**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID", unique = true)
    private Long categoryId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    private Set<LocalizedCategory> localizedCategories;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    private Set<Event> events;
}
```

**LocalizedCategory**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOCALIZED_CATEGORY")
public class LocalizedCategory {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "LOC_CATEGORY_ID")
    private Long locCategoryId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
    private Category category;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "LOCALE")
    private String locale;
}
```